# Haskell depth-first-search for a graph

Tags: algorithm, haskell, graph, functional-programming, depth-first-search

For hours now I am trying to implement a depth-first search for Haskell. My depthfirst algorithm has given a starting node and a graph. That is what I have so far + the definition of the graph datatype.

```
data Graph a = G [a] (BRfun a)
```

with:

```
type BRfun a = a -> [a]
```

current attempt:

```
depthFirst :: Eq a => a -> Graph a -> [a]
depthFirst a (G [a] sucs) = [a]
```

So if only one element is in the nodes list that's the only one I have to put in the final list (I think that should be the cancellation condition).
But now I am struggling to create an recursive algorithm to first get the deepest nodes.

Comment: This will not work, since this is a non-linear pattern matching.

Comment: Depth-first usually does not per se gets the deepest nodes first. It means that we search top-down and then left-to-right, instead of breadth-first that searches left-to-right first, and then top-down.

Comment: Ok can you describe that a little bit more specific? Does that mean that I can just take the first nodes and reverse them when the search algorithm finished?

Comment: You do not need to reverse the list at all, given you construct it correctly (for instance not with *tail* recursion. But first of all I think the type of the function is not correct. Shouldn't it be `Maybe [a]`, or `[[a]]` (since it is possible there is no solution, or that there are multiple solutions).

Comment: Sadly that's no option to change the type :D

Comment: Wait, no/multiple solutions to what exactly? Judging by function signature, nodes just have to be sorted in depth-first order. There's always a solution to that, but cycles might pose a bit of a challenge. I imagine `Eq` constraint is supposed to help with that.

Comment: Anyway, here's a general idea: go down the tree the first chance you get, maintaining the list of nodes you've seen along the way. If a node has no outgoing edges, cool, you're done here. If you've already seen a given node, bail, you don't need infinite recursion. This should be a straightforward application of fold with recursion sprinkled in (probably left fold since you want to traverse top-down left-to-right), something to the tune of `recurse seen node = foldl' recurse ...`. I'm assuming nodes are unique, otherwise `Graph` isn't a very good graph.

Answer (score 2):

I've had one too much of a drink and have a somewhat fuzzy idea of what I'm talking about, but here's a solution I came up with.

```
depthFirst :: Eq a => a -> Graph a -> [a]
depthFirst root (G _nodes edges)
  = reverse $ go [] root
  where
    go seen x
      | x `elem` seen = seen
      | otherwise = foldl' go (x:seen) (edges x)
```

I use `foldl'` from `Data.List` here because we want to traverse nodes left-to-right, which is somewhat challenging with `foldr`. And straight up using `foldl` without `'` is usually not a good idea, since it builds up thunks unless forced (while forcing is exactly what `foldl'` does).

So, the general idea, as I outlined in my comment, is as follows. Go down the tree the first chance you get, maintaining the list of nodes you've seen along the way. If a node has no outgoing edges, cool, you're done here. If you've already seen a given node, bail, you don't need infinite recursion.

Fold starts from current node prepended to the list of already seen nodes (at the beginning, empty list). Then, from left to right, it visits every node directly reachable from current node. At every "next" node, it builds reverse depth-first order of a subtree plus already seen nodes. Already seen nodes are carried over to each "next" node (left-to-right order). If there are no nodes reachable from current node, it returns just current node prepended to list of all seen nodes.

List of seen nodes is reversed because prepending is `O(1)` while appending is `O(n)`. Easier to reverse once and get complexity `O(n)` rather than append every time and get complexity of roughly `O(n²)` (complexities are from the top of my head, and I'm more than a bit tipsy, so apply salt liberally)

If `elem x seen`, function bails returning the list of all nodes seen so far. It makes sure we don't recurse into the nodes we've visited already, and hence avoids infinite recursion on cyclic graphs.

This is classical depth-first search. It could be optimized, and potential for optimization is rather obvious (for one, `elem x seen` has `O(n)` worst-case complexity, while it could've been `O(log n)`. Feel free to improve on the code.

As a last bit of advice, type of `Graph` doesn't guarantee that nodes are unique. A stricter implementation would look like this: `data Graph a = G (Set a) (BRfun a)`, where `Set` is from `Data.Set` (or something similar). Given the stated definition with list, it *might* be a good idea to relabel all nodes, f.ex. `nodes' = zip [1..] nodes` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

For graph searches like DFS and BFS, you need to keep around a list of vertices that you've previously visited. This makes it possible to check if you've seen a vertex before, so that you don't visit a vertex twice (and this handles cycles too, although it can't actually detect for sure if cycles exist).

Here's my implementation. The `visited` list keeps track of which vertices have been visited. For each vertex we encounter, we check to see if it's been visited by traversing the list. When we "visit" a vertex (that is, in the `else` branch), we add the vertex to the list. The visited list is kept up-to-date by passing it around in the `foldl`.

In this approach, we can actually hijack the `visited` list for recording the depth-first order. Since we add vertices to the list when we first see them, the `visited` list is in *reverse* depth-first order. So we simply reverse it once the search has completed.

```
depthFirst source (G _ sucs) = reverse (search [] source)
  where
    search visited v =
      if v `elem` visited
      then visited -- already seen v, so skip it
      else foldl search (v:visited) (sucs v)
```

I'd recommend walking through how the code executes on a small graph to get a sense for how it works and why it is correct. For example, try it on the graph defined as follows, from source 0.

```
edges = [[1,2,3],[4],[5],[4,6],[5],[1],[4]]
g = G [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] (edges!!)
```

Finally, note that this implementation is correct but highly inefficient, taking time O(nm) for a graph of n vertices and m edges, because we traverse the visited list once per edge. In a more efficient implementation, you would want to keep around two data structures, one for looking up whether or not a vertex has been visited (such as a hash set or binary search tree) and a second one for writing down the depth-first ordering.